# Android how to implement Blowfish / crypt(3) / $2y$ algorithm in Android

Tags: android, algorithm, encryption, blowfish

I have a requirement in app to send some encrypted data to server. The server-side has told me to use Blowfish / crypt(3) / $2y$ and send him the encrypted data. I am using following code to get work done:

```
public String encrypt(String data) {
    String Key = "My_PRIVATE_KEY";
    try {
        byte[] KeyData = Key.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec KS = new SecretKeySpec(KeyData, "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KS);
        return bytesToHex(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes()));

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private String bytesToHex(byte[] data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int len = data.length;
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ((data[i] & 0xFF) < 16) {
            str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
        }
        else {
            str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

but I am getting wrong results. I tried to print the algorithm names that are supported  in andoid using:

```
String msg = "";
    Object[] o = Security.getAlgorithms("Cipher").toArray();
    for (int i=0; i<o.length; i++) {
        msg = msg + "\n" + ((String)o[i]);
    }
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt)).setText(msg);
```

It shows BLOWFISH in the list but not something like crypt (3) 2y. can anybody guide me to the right direction...???
I am using [QuickHash](https://quickhash.com/) to check output validity.

Answer (score 0):

`crypt`, when used with `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` is actually defining the bcrypt Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF). So you should use a Java compatible version of bcrypt, e.g. [this one](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/).

Comment: Note that I cannot vouch for the security of the implementation I pointed to.

Comment: thanks for link. I also tried jBCrypt. Its working was strange. I used  String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(password, "My Salt String"); in my code. If I pass my salt something like "1234567890123456789123456" it starts giving exception like invalid salt version, invalid salt rounds. But if i provide salt like "$2$07$1234567890123456789123456$", it gives no error but wrong output. But the strange thing is that if I used the second salt in php, the output was similar to android one. Can you please guide me a little?

Comment: sorry it was "$2a$07$1234567890123456789123456$".

Comment: If we assume that the salt is correct - and it must be otherwise you would not get a similar answer - then there are three other variables: the strength (set to 7 in above example I suppose) and the character encoding used for the password. Could you try and see if any of these matter? It seems that the Java bcrypt uses UTF-8. Compare salt strings by letting the Java bcrypt generate one itself.